# Password reset is not working in loopback 3.0

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I've been trying to implement the reset password functionality in my project which uses nodejs and loopback version 3.0 . Loopback provides in built method for this reset password functionality in the user.js.
When I run the project and and test the reset password it runs without giving any errors but the email is not received.

This is the inbuilt method given by loopback for password reset functionality.

```
 User.resetPassword = function(options, cb) {
    // console.log("options : "+options);
    // console.log("cb : "+cb);
    cb = cb || utils.createPromiseCallback();
    var UserModel = this;
    var ttl = UserModel.settings.resetPasswordTokenTTL || DEFAULT_RESET_PW_TTL;
    options = options || {};
    if (typeof options.email !== 'string') {
      var err = new Error(g.f('Email is required'));
      err.statusCode = 400;
      err.code = 'EMAIL_REQUIRED';
      cb(err);
      return cb.promise;
    }

    try {
      if (options.password) {
        UserModel.validatePassword(options.password);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    var where = {
      email: options.email,
    };
    if (options.realm) {
      where.realm = options.realm;
    }
    UserModel.findOne({where: where}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        err = new Error(g.f('Email not found'));
        err.statusCode = 404;
        err.code = 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND';
        return cb(err);
      }
      // create a short lived access token for temp login to change password
      // TODO(ritch) - eventually this should only allow password change
      if (UserModel.settings.emailVerificationRequired && !user.emailVerified) {
        err = new Error(g.f('Email has not been verified'));
        err.statusCode = 401;
        err.code = 'RESET_FAILED_EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED';
        return cb(err);
      }

      if (UserModel.settings.restrictResetPasswordTokenScope) {
        const tokenData = {
          ttl: ttl,
          scopes: ['reset-password'],
        };
        user.createAccessToken(tokenData, options, onTokenCreated);
      } else {
        // We need to preserve backwards-compatibility with
        // user-supplied implementations of "createAccessToken"
        // that may not support "options" argument (we have such
        // examples in our test suite).
        user.createAccessToken(ttl, onTokenCreated);
      }

      function onTokenCreated(err, accessToken) {
        if (err) {
          return cb(err);
        }
        cb();
        UserModel.emit('resetPasswordRequest', {
            email: options.email,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            user: user,
            options: options,
          }
        );
      }
    });

    return cb.promise;
  };
```

[When i enter the email from loopback api for password reset it gives no errors in the console but the email is not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0esQ4.png)

The method resetPassword is called during the process.Console log inside the method is printed as shown below.

```
{ email: '**********@gmail.com',
  authorizedRoles: { '$everyone': true } }
[Function: callback]
```

The thing which confuses me is that the verify email method is working 
which is also comes inbuilt in the user.js .The following is printed in the console when the verification email is sent.

```
mx resolved:  [ { exchange: 'alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 10 },
  { exchange: 'alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 20 },
  { exchange: 'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 5 },
  { exchange: 'alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 40 },
  { exchange: 'alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', priority: 30 } ]
MX connection created:  alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
recv gmail.com>220 mx.google.com ESMTP 1si9238203plw.390 - gsmtp
send gmail.com>EHLO gmail.com
recv gmail.com>250-mx.google.com at your service, [112.135.5.40]
recv gmail.com>250-SIZE 157286400
recv gmail.com>250-8BITMIME
recv gmail.com>250-STARTTLS
recv gmail.com>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
recv gmail.com>250-PIPELINING
recv gmail.com>250 SMTPUTF8
send gmail.com>MAIL FROM:<hasikasadaruwan.mgtuk@gmail.com>
recv gmail.com>452 (IP, Sender) first encounter.
```

It would be a great help if anyone help me to solve this problem, I've been stuck here for days. 
            THANKS in advance.

Comment: I solved this problem as shown in this  https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management

Answer (score 2):

You must handle resetPasswordRequest endpoint in your extended model like this.

```
MyUser.on("resetPasswordRequest", function(info) {
console.log(info.email); // the email of the requested user
console.log(info.accessToken.id); // the temp access token to allow password reset

var url = "http://**********";
var html =
  'Click <a href="' +
  url +
  "?access_token=" +
  info.accessToken.id +
  '">here</a> to reset your password.</br><h2>Link will be expired in 15 minutes.';
//'here' in above html is linked to : 'http://<host:port>/reset-password?access_token=<short-lived/temporary access token>'
MyUser.app.models.Email.send(
  {
    to: info.email,
    from: senderAddress,
    subject: "Password reset",  
    html: html
  },
  function(err) {
    if (err) return console.log("> error sending password reset email");
    console.log("> sending password reset email to:", info.email);
  }
);  });
```

Provide URL of your form. On that form submit use reset-password endpoint.
Checkout this reference: [loopback-example-user-management](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management/blob/68826156dd7bc438d49467f94ae2fba82b549c23/common/models/user.js#L53)

This worked for me. Thank you!